# One-Click Web Deploy failing: "This method is not supported by this class."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy, one-click-web-publishing

I've found a lot of articles on web deploy and why it might fail, but not any with answers with this error message.

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL `https://myserver:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=mysite`.)
>
> Could not complete the request to remote agent URL `https://myserver:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=mysitename`. The request was aborted: The request was canceled. This method is not supported by this class.

I am trying to deploy an MVC4 website from Visual Studio 2013 Express to a Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter server with the Web Server role installed.

I followed [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx) (and other installation guides) and can confirm the following:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
- Web Server role installed
- Management Services is running

  - Accepting windows and IIS credentials
  - Server `Administrator` has permissions
  - Remote connections enabled (and service restarted)
  - SSL certificate is our real one, not the self-cert
- My firewall is configured to allow this traffic
- I **am** prompted for a username/password when accessing `https://myserver:8172/msdeploy.axd`
- The website is running

  - Bound to all IPs on `:80` and `:443` (with same cert as deploy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason, it didn't want the Windows Administrator account doing a deploy.

- Created an IIS user in `IIS Manager User`
- Changed the permission settings to `Windows credentials or IIS manager credentials`

  - Restarted `Management Service`
- Added the newly created user to the website

### it works!